# How to interface the xbee s2 module with devices that works at baud rate of 4800?

Tags: xbee

I have to transmit the GPS data to pc wirelessly through Xbee S2 and that GPS module works at 4800 baud rate.I have used Xbee at baud rate of 9600 only.Once I have tried to change it to 19200 and it damaged my Xbee module.So  I am scared to change the Xbee configuration to 4800. How can I use my Xbee module to transmit the data of GPS device that works  in 4800 of baud rate?.Can I change it to 4800? or is there any other way of changing the baud rate? any help would be appreciated. Thanks !! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can change the baud rate of the serial interface of an XBee module by setting the `ATBD` parameter.  X-CTU has a table showing some of the values, where `2` corresponds to 4800 baud.  On many of the XBee modules, you can also use the actual baud rate (so `ATBD4800` to set it to 4800 baud).

The XBee sends data over the radio at a fixed baud rate, and XBee devices on a network can have different baud rates on their serial interfaces.